# Facebook follow button failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, facebook, button

I see there are multiple posts here on stackoverflow and else where on the web regarding this issue. Needless to say I couldn't find a solution from any of those posts. Apparently this used to be a bug but that was back in 2009, surely they would've fixed this now.

I'm referring to [this button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/follow/) . By default we have Mr Zuck himself set for the button, but when I type in my facebook URL /deangrobler89 it doesn't work. I've also tried a few of my other FB friends to see if it works with their profiles and it doesn't either.

The error I get in the Chrome console reads:

> Failed to load resource.

The resource being:

> file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1

Any idea how I can finaly get this button to work?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see a "Follow" button on your own profile if you log out of FB?

You probably need to enable followers in your profile settings. Regular users can have followers too, you don't need to be a celebrity!

Account Setting -> Followers -> Turn On Follow.

Comment: Sorry, when I looked more closely at your question, this turned out not to be the immediate problem. See the other answer below!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured this one out. Normal accounts, accounts like mine and yours, can't have a "follow" button. Only pages or RSS feeds so to speak can have follow pages. So this would mostly be companies and brands. Not people.

Of course Zuckerburg also has a RSS you can subscribe to thus the "follow" button.

Comment: Yes, Pages are probably after the [Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), not [Follow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/follow/) , button.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet, the URI is given as
"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=0";

This is only going to work if you're viewing it over http or https. (The "//" part of the URI means to match the protocol of the parent page. This is to get around "unsafe JS" warnings if you load http JavaScript on an https page.)

I'm guessing that you tried this out initially with a local .html file on your hard drive? :)

So, either change "//" to "https://" or move that code to a real web host.